# Converting hexadecimal to binary example

Tags: python, binary

I do not seem to understand the error of this code. I am trying to convert from hexadecimal to decimal. For example for a hexadecimal string that starts with 0x. Can someone help me, please? Thank you

```
def hex_char_decode(digit):  # 0xbadf00d
    if digit[0:2] == "0x":
        digit = digit[2:]
    bit_index = len(digit) - 1
    sum = 0
    i = 0
    while bit_index >= 0:
        if digit[len] >= "0" and digit[len] <= "9":
            res = int(digit[len])
        elif digit[len] >= "A" and digit[len] <= "F":
            res = ord(digit[len]) - 55
        elif hex[len] >= 'a' and hex[len] <= 'f':
            res = ord(digit[len]) - 87
        else:
            sum = 1
            break
        sum += (res * (16 ** i))
        bit_index -= 1
        i += 1
        return sum


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # you should have all your main logic including inputs.
    # function calls and output inside of if statement.
    hexa = input()
    result = hex_char_decode(hexa)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Is this an assignment? Do you need to do all the manual work? Because  `int()` works to convert the strings: `int("0xff", base=16)` ->  `255`

Comment: The error in your code is `digit[len]`.  `len` is a builtin function in Python — it doesn't make sense to use it as an index. It's not clear what you meant that to be. Did you mean `digit[bit_index]`?